# Robocopy to delete required file only after it copied all newer files

Tags: backup, robocopy

There is one aspect of Robocopy that cannot be optimized using its options: it deletes files before copying new ones.

The example may be clearer if we consider moving some files already copied between two folders. Robocopy will first delete the no longer existing files from the old folder, then copy the files from the new folder. This aspect means that there is a moment, albeit perhaps brief, in which I DO NOT HAVE backups for the moved files, because they are deleted first, and then re-copied, or in any case it is not available an option to configure robocopy to make copies of the new files FIRST and only at the end delete those that no longer exist.

I think the only solution is to run robocopy twice with the right options, the first time excluding the deletions (/XX ?), the second complete.

Is anyone paranoid enough to have encountered this problem before?